# Product inspection with Computer vision - edge detection with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am a new user of opencv. I am currently doing a project of performing product inspection with opencv. I was planning to extract edges of good product and the bad product then compare their edges maybe with mean square difference. However, it is already quite difficult to extract the edge clearly as the first step.

Good sample:**Good product**
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
When I use canny edge detection, the edge of the good product (the blue part of the picture) only includes part of the product and is as follows:
**Edge of good product**
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I also tried to use adaptiveThreshold to make the greyscale picture more clear and then use the edge detection. But, the edge detected is not as good as expected because of many noise.

Therefore, I would like to ask for a solution of extracting the edge or any better way of comparing good product and bad product with opencv. Sorry for the bad english above.

Comment: best would probably be to get a better suitable lighting and a uniform background

Comment: Thanks! If I can successfully extract the edges of good and bad products, what kind of comparison method should I use to further test about the two edges? If I use square difference or direct difference of pixel by pixel, it seems to be a unexpected difference due to shifted image. Therefore, I would like to ask if there is any method of aligning two images with opencv so that I can directly extract or use square difference to calculate the similarity of two images.

Comment: sample images are missing

Comment: typically you first have to match the position, for example with homography extraction or IPC. after that you could use shape descriptors or chamfer matching for example.

Comment: also please provide an image of bad product

Answer (score 0):

This task can be made simple if some assumptions like those below are valid. For example:

1. Products move along the same production line, and therefore the lighting across all product images stays the same.
2. The products lie on a flat surface parallel to the focal plane of the camera, so the rotation of objects will be only around the axis of the lens.
3. The lighting can be controlled (this will help you to get better edges, and is actually used in production line image processing)

Since we cannot see the images that you added, it is a bit hard to see what exactly the situation is. But if the above assumptions are valid, image differencing combined with image signatures is one possible approach.

Another possibility is to train a Haar Cascade classifier using good and bad products. With this, the edges and all that will be taken care of. But you will have to collect a lot of data and train the classifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot ~ What I am planning to do is as follows:
1. Use OPENCV template matching function, good product as template. Then it will extract the region of interest from the testing image. It sounds the template matching function can make sure the two images are aligned (orientation).
2. Use Opencv shape distance to calculate the difference between template and testing image.

As I am still in testing period, I am not sure if the above ways work or not.

Comment: I have used opencv Shape_example as the foundation. I tried to compare identical images using shape_example codes... However, I observed different distance number appear even for identical images.... I was expecting 0 or very very closed to 0 for identical image comparison...

The source code can be found :https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/shape_example.cpp